# Alignment of labeled vector with other vectos

Tags: matrices, vector

I would like create 3 line vectors that are directly aligned to each other. I would to label the first vector (here example A, B, C ...) However the alignment (and the size of the brackts does not really work out. Does someone have a suggestion on this?

```
\begin{align}
p_{A} &= \bordermatrix{~  & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \cr
              ~ & 0,01 & 0,49 & 0,02 & 0,00 & 0,01 & 0,26 & 0,1 & 0,11\cr} \\
p_{B} &= \begin{pmatrix}
0,10 & 0,17 & 0,65 & 0,01 & 0,01 & 0,02 & 0,01 & 0,03 \\  
\end{pmatrix} \\                                     
\end{align}
```

Would be great if you could help me on this

Best

Comment: I think you shouldn't force it to be vector. Make a table instead of an ugly vectorish thing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility, with TABstacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\setstackTAB{@}
\setstacktabbedgap{1em}% INTERCOLUMN GAP
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
p_{A} =\phantom{(} \tabbedstackon[5pt]% THE 5pt IS THE GAP TO THE OVERSET
  {\llap{(}0,01 @ 0,49 @ 0,02 @ 0,00 @ 0,01 @ 0,26 @ 0,10 @ 0,11\rlap{)}}
             {A @ B @ C @ D @ E @ F @ G @ H} \\
p_{B} = \phantom{(} \tabbedShortstack{
\llap{(}0,10 @ 0,17 @ 0,65 @ 0,01 @ 0,01 @ 0,02 @ 0,01 @ 0,03\rlap{)}}                           
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The standard `array` environment is good, but if the entries are decimal numbers it's better to use `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}
First the version with the standard \texttt{array}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r @{} *{8}{c} @{} l}
         &  A   &  B   &  C   &  D   &  E   &  F   &  G   &  H      \\
p_{A} = (& 0,01 & 0,49 & 0,02 & 0,00 & 0,01 & 0,26 & 0,10 & 0,11 &) \\
p_{B} = (& 0,10 & 0,17 & 0,65 & 0,01 & 0,01 & 0,02 & 0,01 & 0,03 &)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
and then the version with \texttt{siunitx}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r @{} *{8}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{} l}
         & {A}  & {B}  & {C}  & {D}  & {E}  & {F}  & {G}  & {H}     \\
p_{A} = (& 0,01 & 0,49 & 0,02 & 0,00 & 0,01 & 0,26 & 0,10 & 0,11 &) \\
p_{B} = (& 0,10 & 0,17 & 0,65 & 0,01 & 0,01 & 0,02 & 0,01 & 0,03 &)
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the two lines need to be numbered, then one can do it with the help
of `gather`:

```
\begin{gather}
\nonumber\\
\\
\smash{
  \begin{array}[b]{r @{} *{8}{S[table-format=1.2]} @{} l}
           & {A}  & {B}  & {C}  & {D}  & {E}  & {F}  & {G}  & {H}     \\[\jot]
  p_{A} = (& 0,01 & 0,49 & 0,02 & 0,00 & 0,01 & 0,26 & 0,10 & 0,11 &) \\[\jot]
  p_{B} = (& 0,10 & 0,17 & 0,65 & 0,01 & 0,01 & 0,02 & 0,01 & 0,03 &)
  \end{array}
}
\end{gather}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to get both `$p_A$` and `$p_B$` lines numbered? I was working on a similar solution but I couldn't find how to get both numbered as in the original code.

Comment: @PaulGessler Added.